# Using ICACLS to set permissions on folder and new files, but excluding a specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions, icacls, cacls

I am trying to use ICACLS to set the permissions on a directory. I want all new and existing objects in the directory to have the permissions I set, EXCEPT one specific folder I know the name of. This folder does not need the permissions and is incredibly large so it causes ICACLS to take a very long time.

How can I do this? I saw some posts about separating ICACLS commands into two, but whenever I do a /grant on the parent directory, it seems to always be recursive and ends up going through the large directory.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
ICACLS C:\Folder /grant Users:(OI)CI)F
```

If I leave out the `(OI)(CI)` and just have `F`, it does not work.

Comment: You need to change the ACL on the *child* folder.  Specifically, you need to disable inheritance.  The `/inheritance:d` option will do that.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks. so just calling /inheritance:d on the child folder I want to exclude and then using /grant on the parent folder?